# If and vlookup functions being used together

Tags: excel

Can anyone see why this wouldn't work? the vlookup section works fine if I separate it from the if statement.

The only thing I can think of is that it doesn't like the range being used with the if statement, has anyone any other ideas on how to do this?

```
=IF('3423'!D:D=1,VLOOKUP(MAX('3423'!$A:$A),'3423'!$A1:$AC23,5,FALSE),"")
```

Thanks 
Paula

Comment: Presuming that `='3423'!D1` works on it's own?

Comment: @Tim Edwards apologies I posted my D1 testing code its the one displayed above now with a range that doesn't work but if I swap it to D1=1 that does work

Comment: What's the error message given? I'd play about with it a bit and maybe split the two parts into separate cells, i.e. Z1 being `='3423'!D:D=1` and then Z2 being `=IF(Z1,VLOOKUP(MAX('3423'!$A:$A),'3423'!$A1:$AC23,5,FALSE),"")` just to try and work out which part is causing your issue.

Comment: this seems like array formula. You can try entering it with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: @Slai, indeed it seems like OPs trying to find the max of one column based on other criteria. VLOOKUP is probably the wrong approach and maybe better off with array for something like `=MAX(IF(` etc.

Comment: The part that is broken is IF('3423'!D:D=1 the rest all works fine when I separate it out. My only problem with swapping to a =MAX(If( approach is that I need it to look up column D and if the criteria is met then it needs to go to column A and find the largest out of the bunch then I need it to look to column 5 and lift that number and paste it into the relevant cell.

Answer (score 0):

It wont let me complete it with a single column reference so if I put in cell references D3:D1000 and swap it to an array it displays the correct information